# HTML 5 custom validation for radio button group not working

Tags: html

I want to add a custom validation message to my radio buttons  group that I have.

It works fine in the below conditions:

1. If I select the second radio button "female" and click on submit.
2. If I select the first radio button "male" and click on submit.
3. If I do not select any radio button and click on submit, it shows me the validation message. On selecting the first radio button and clicking submit, the form is submitted.

It does not work in the below condition:

1. If I click on submit without checking any radio button, it shows me the validation message. After that if I select the second radio button "female" and click on submit, it still shows me the validation message on the first radio button "male".

Below is the code I have written

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="overlay">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <form id="myForm">
        <div class="row">
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required 
          oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please select your gender')"
          oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
          <label for="male">Male</label>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" required
          oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please select your gender')"
          oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
          <label for="female">Female</label>
          <br>
         </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <input class="submit_button" type="submit" value="Submit">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I know this custom validation issue can be fixed by writing a function in javascript/jquery. But I would like to know if there is a way to do this inline or if there is any documentation that states it cannot be done.

**Note** : If I do not put the custom validation code `oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please select your gender')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"`. All the conditions work correctly.

Comment: Where is your JS ?

Comment: Is JS needed? As the issue is with the inline custom validation

Comment: why don't you put the default value selected?

Comment: You can not do like this on a radio buttons it will throw validation error one way or other- are you open to use a but JS ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="overlay">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <form id="myForm">
        <div class="row">
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="male">
          <label for="male">Male</label>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="female">
          <label for="female">Female</label>
          <br>
         </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <input class="submit_button" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="ValidateForm(this.form)">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateForm(form){
        ErrorText= "";
        if ( ( form.gender[0].checked == false ) && ( form.gender[1].checked == false ) )
        {
        alert ( "Please select your gender" );
        return false;
        }
        if (ErrorText= "") { form.submit() }
    }
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, the code you have shared works fine. But I want to have a custom validation message shown.

Comment: @swithencolaco, This is a radio button for the gender field. Users will choose either Male or Female. So what you want to show on validation?

Comment: I want a custom validation message to be shown "'Please select your gender'" instead of "Please select one of these options"

Comment: Got any solution for this @swithen colaco

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required 
      oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please select your gender')"
      oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">

      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" required
      oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please select your gender')"
      oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
```

try this instead (no JS technically):

```
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required
           oninvalid="if(!document.querySelector('input[name=\'gender\'][checked=true]').length >= 1)this.setCustomValidity('Please select your gender')"
           oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">

    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" required
           oninvalid="if(!document.querySelector('input[name=\'gender\'][checked=true]').length >= 1)this.setCustomValidity('Please select your gender')"
           oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
```

Working [link](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GH8RJ998ETMF)

Comment: The code doesn't work. The validation message shown is the default one and not the one set. ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null``` is the javascript console error